# What is the Time Complexity of a PriorityQueue add() and poll() in this case

Tags: queue, time-complexity, big-o, priority-queue

If I have a PriorityQueue of size 4, and I am iterating over an array of size 'n', and I only want the 4 greatest elements in the array. By the time I reach the end of the array, did this program take O(n) time, or O(nlogn) time. I know PQ add() and remove() take O(logn), but because the PQ size will never be greater than 4, does that mean that this is an O(n) program.

Here is the code if you wish to reference

````
class Solution {
    public int minDifference(int[] nums) {
        if(nums.length <= 4) return 0;
       PriorityQueue<Integer> maxq = new PriorityQueue();
       PriorityQueue<Integer> minq = new PriorityQueue(new Comparator<Integer>(){
           public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
               return (a - b) * -1;
           }
       });
      
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            if(minq.size() < 4){
                minq.add(nums[i]);
                maxq.add(nums[i]);
            }else
            {
            
            if(nums[i] > maxq.peek()){
                maxq.poll();
                maxq.add(nums[i]);
            }
            
            if(nums[i] < minq.peek()){
                minq.poll();
                minq.add(nums[i]);
            }
            }
        }
        
        int smallest4 =  minq.poll();
        int smallest3 = minq.poll();
        int smallest2 = minq.poll();
        int smallest = minq.poll();
        
        int biggest4 = maxq.poll();
        int biggest3 = maxq.poll();
        int biggest2 = maxq.poll();
        int biggest = maxq.poll();
        
        int remove3End = biggest4 - smallest;
        int remove3Beg = biggest - smallest4;
        int twoEnd_oneStart = biggest3 - smallest2;
        int oneEnd_twoStart = biggest2 - smallest3;
        
        int a = Math.min(remove3End,remove3Beg);
        int b = Math.min(twoEnd_oneStart, oneEnd_twoStart);
        
        return Math.min(a,b);

        
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

> I know PQ add() and remove() take O(logn), but because the PQ size will never be greater than 4, does that mean that this is an O(n) program?

Yes, you are right about that. The `n` in O(logn) is actually 4, so it becomes O(log4), which is O(1). So you can just say that `add()` and `remove()` run in constant time for your case.